# no element error on ajaxing to php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to connect my javascript and php files and I get no element error and I couldn't figure out. Thanks for help in advance!
+anyone can recommend ways to debug these..?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>AJAX!!!!</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

</head>

<body>

<h1>HOME</h1>

<h4>Enter Your ID</h4>

<p>summoners name: <input type="text" id="summonerName"></p>
<button id="sumName">Search!</button>

<button id="renewData"> Renew Data</button>

<button id="testing"> Renew Data</button>

<div id="result">Display result</div>

<script src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>


<script type = "text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$('#testing').on('click', function(){

    $.ajax({
      type : 'GET',
      url: 'test.php',
      data : {str: $("#summonerName").val()},
      success: function (msg) {
         $('#result').html("hh");
      },
      error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
      });

});
```

});

});

and my php file

```
<?php

    if ($_GET['str']) : 
        echo "yes";
    endif;
?>
```

had to delete some functions in javascript part

Comment: check error in console of your browser

Comment: `console.log`  which willl  print log messages in your developer console (firebug/webkit dev tools/ie dev tools)

Comment: is path to your ajax url correct?? I think its weong

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju how would it be wrong? I followed that from examples

Comment: where is your file and test.php, ??

Comment: the file should be present is same root of the file where your ajax call is present.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju the files are both in the same folder. the html file and php file

Comment: run your .php file from browser,

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju oh.. I cannot.. is there something that I have to do more to make php files? sorry I'm a beginner I thought I could make the file just like html

Comment: u have xampp installed on ur machine??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju yes and the server is running

Comment: @Pedro Lobito - Yes, it is php. It's an alternative syntax more popularly used in view templating.

Comment: wen ur running .php file what you r getting?? any errors??

Comment: @PedroLobito uhh... I got the syntax from a tutorial

Comment: @KaylaJin Run your test.php file in your browser from your xampp location. You must see what's the output there. Add more output to the script. Say some else in between.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju I'm getting this errror print

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju Notice: Undefined index: str in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test.php on line 5

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju thanks for the massive help by the way..

Comment: i think no problem with php code. for ajax check in console, if you r getting any error??

Comment: @KaylaJin - Yes that warning is because you aren't passing the str variable if just running test.php. Try  running this: test.php?str=hello

Comment: is your `.html` file present in `/htdocs` directory??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju no element found test.php:22:3
no element found testAjax.html:22:3

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju I put all my files (3files -jquery, html, php) in /htdocs

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju 
<button id="testing"> Renew Data</button>
//line 22 of testAjax
<div id="result">Display result</div>

Comment: can you add complete data of .html file??

Comment: You must give ouput to the error text param in the error callback. That has the error info.

Comment: replace `alert()` in error with this and see what is coming
`alert(errorThrown);`

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju I updated it. Sorry I had to format it and delete functions that include my api key.. I also added the css file in the directory in case but that wasn't the isssue

Comment: what is alert giveng??

Comment: There is extra `});` at end your code, also forgot to write `</script>` at end. Is it by mistake ?

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju oh. the console told me I have an invalid XML error

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju the refresh on firefox didn't work somehow for the past minutes..

Comment: @SumanBogati I had to delete some functions that had my private info so it's probably mistake in deleting :)

Comment: Clear the history of browser and see what happens?

Comment: @SumanBogati it's still the same..

Comment: I'm pretty sure the file is php file though. I looked at its info and it says PHP script I'm not sure what's going on

Comment: Have you seen my answer which is working fine at jsfiddle?

Comment: give the file url `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sumanbogati/test/master/test.php` instead of `test.php`

Comment: @SumanBogati I did. Thanks for the input but I want to make more php files later so I want to fix the issue on my local computer :)

Comment: So by giving online url for `test.php` is working fine?

Comment: what is alert in error showing??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju Error: Invalid XML: <?php

 echo "hello world";

?>

Comment: maybe my computer doesn't read php? isn't having xampp on mac enough to make php files?

Comment: yes xampp is enough, and it seems that your php is not getting parsed. Try to run code with restarting the apache.

Comment: @SumanBogati nope.. lol it doesn't work.. I don't understand what is going on lol

Comment: It's for sure that your php is not executing by your apache. You can give a try for backup the current xampp and install new xampp. See what happens with new xampp.

Comment: @SumanBogati although it's working when I do localhost/test.php? I will give it a try still

Comment: welp not working either... thanks for the help guys though.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I run your code with [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L22079ty/) which is working fine. The may helps to you.

**HTML**

```
<div id="result"></div>

<button id="testing">Get External Content</button>
```

**JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    //testing is a button

    $('#testing').on('click', function(){

            $.ajax({
              type : 'GET',
              url:'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sumanbogati/test/master/test.php',
              data : {str: $("#sum").val()},
              success: function (msg) {
                 $('#result').html("hh");
              },
              error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("error getsasadds!"); //this statement is given out
                }
              });

    });
});
```

Comment: i think this is not an answer to the question this is more like a advice so this should go to comment

Comment: @SumanBogati Could you tell me one more thing? so, I used your url and the html is doing the correct thing. Would it be still the XAMPP problem or did I possibly format something wrong in php?

Comment: I also redownloaded the the xampp too

Comment: Make the folder and put all your files inside it, and put this folder in gihtub and share the link here..

Answer (score 0):

The reason is in your php code. It just throws no error, that's why success callback is executed.